# Is it possible to call the finalize method to a int or vector?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Is it possible to call the finalize method to a int or vector in Java?

Comment: don't freak out. For example in C#, even int are objects, so they have methods.

Comment: @Seva: I'm not freaking out, but you have several bad assumptions present, and most important, this is not C#.

Comment: NEVER call the finalize method.

Comment: I think if the finalize method exists, it has some utility. So calm down. :P

Comment: @Seva: please stop sounding foolish.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, that sounds so gay

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `int` is not an object and does not have methods.

A `java.util.Vector` has (like any object) a `finalize()` method, but it is called automatically when the object is garbage collected.

You should never write a `finalize()` method that is meant to be called explicitly, because that would be a flagrant violation of the principle of least surprise.

Comment: am I able to modify the finalize method of the vector? thanks

Comment: @Seva: yes you are able to, but no you should not do this. Calling this method does **not** make an object garbage collected.

Comment: I know that it doesnt ensure, but I would like to check the size of the vector in bytes and sum to a variable before the garbage collector take the object. How do I do this please?

Comment: @Seva: why didn't you put this in your original post. You can extend Vector and override its finalize method, but this will usually prolong its lifetime and thus make it less likely to be garbage collected in a timely manner. Please see the link in my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I think some are "freaking out" because it has so many incorrect assumptions in the question.

`int` is a primitive so it doesn't have a finalize method to call.

`Vector` is a legacy class which was replaced in Java 1.2 (1998) by ArrayList. It has a finalise method which is protected.  `protected` means it should only be called from a sub-class. So you cannot access it easily.

However, I don't suggest you call finalize on Vector or any other class.  If you have a finalize method which has functionality you would like to call, create a public method which does the same thing rather than call finalise()

BTW: Even if you did call Vector.finalize() it doesn't do anything. It inherits Object.finalize() which is `{}`

Answer (score 2):

What is your motivation for this and how does this relate to garbage collection?  To make an object collectable, you need to remove all strong references to it, **not** call finalize.

Please read this important reference on Garbage collection, and in particular the section on Finalized, section A.3.6 [The Truth About Garbage Collection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppGC.fm.html)

Comment: dont you think the finalize method is related to garbage collector?

Comment: @Seva: I don't say it's not related. I do say that you shouldn't call it directly and that calling it does not make an object collectablle. The Java VM will call finalize if it is present before an object's memory is deallocated. **Again** please look at the link above as it's all spelled out there.

Comment: I think if the finalize method exists, it has some utility. So calm down. :P. I will put + 1 for you.

Comment: @Seva: I am calm, but don't care for others putting words in my mouth. I never said it doesn't have utility, just that you shouldn't call it directly, and that it's "utility" is well spelled out in the link above.

Answer (score 2):

The method `finalize()` is inherited from `java.lang.Object`. Java `int` is a primitive type and these types are not considered objects, therefore it is not possible to invoke finalize on these.